# How to Change the Color of Formulas in a Large MS-Word Document Automatically?

Tags: vba, ms-word

As the title states, I have a large word document with bunch of formulas in it. Is it possible to write a macro to detect formula and change the color automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your formulas are have been inserted using Word's *Equations* command, you will be able to access the formulas by enumerating all elements of the `ActiveDocument.OMaths` collection. You can then apply formatting such as a text color using the following VBA macro:

```
Sub FormatOMaths()

    Dim formula As OMath

    For Each formula In ActiveDocument.OMaths
        formula.Range.Font.TextColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh nice! Exactly what I needed! Thanks!